# Removing page from content database via feature deactivation

Tags: visual-studio, page-layout, feature-activation

I deployed page via module. Module is deployed via feature (method FeatureActivated). After that process page is deployed in content database.

**What I need is to be  able to delete (remove) page from database after feature deactivation (method FeatureDeactivating)** For now, I can't see any page collection properties in my web to be able to get and delete my page from it. 
I assume that this is maybe possible to do via PowerShell or CA, but I need to do that from VS.

Please, any suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should check this:

[Removing Provisioned Files from SharePoint During Feature Deactivation](http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/removing-provisioned-files-from-sharepoint-during-feature-deactivation/)

Comment: Dobro misliš Vedrane :) This is solution for problem. Thank you!